# Fixing simultaneous memory access error for array of custom class iOS

Tags: ios, memory-management, swift3, crash, xcode9.1

in my app I've a viewcontroller with tableview and when it load it gives me about 12 simultaneous memory error all in same place where I try to remove the element from my custom array. Below are the related codes

In my viewcontroller where table loads I've accesses the method as below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    //Some Code 

    arrangeTableObject.arrangetableSectionsInOrderForNoteType(withFrameId:tableDataSection.frameId.uintValue)

   //Some code
   return cell
}
```

In my another swift class arrangeTableObject.swift this is how I've used the methods

```
//My custom array is defined as
var tableSections : [TableSection]?

func arrangetableSectionsInOrderForNoteType(type: NoteType){

        var tableIndex = 0

        if tableSectionForItemType(itemType: .tableItemNoteItems) != nil  {

            let noteItemSection = tableSectionForItemType(itemType: .tableItemNoteItems)
            removetableSectionWithFrameId(itemType: . tableItemNoteItems)
            tableSections?.insert(noteItemSection!, at: tableIndex)
            tableIndex += 1
        }


        if let commentSection = tableSectionForItemType(itemType: .tableItemComment) {
            removetableSectionWithFrameId(itemType: .tableItemComment)
            tableSections?.insert(commentSection, at: tableIndex)
            tableIndex+=1
        }


        if tableSectionForItemType(itemType: .tableItemAtAGlance) != nil {

            let otherSection = tableSectionForItemType(itemType: .tableItemOtherItems)
            removetableSectionWithFrameId(itemType: . tableItemOtherItems)
            tableSections?.insert(otherSection!, at: tableIndex)
            tableIndex += 1

        }


    }
```

//This is the method where it shows error

```
func removetableSectionWithFrameId(itemType : tableItemType){

        if tableSections?.count != 0 {
            for section in tableSections! {

                if section.itemType == itemType {
                 //Error points to this line below
                        self.tableSections?.remove(at: self.tableSections!.index(of: section)!) 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For fixing I tried to add sync lock using the method below

```
func sync(lock: NSObject, closure: () -> Void) {
        objc_sync_enter(lock)
        closure()
        objc_sync_exit(lock)
    }
```

I tried to modify the section where the error occurred as below but it still throws me the same error

```
if section.itemType == itemType {
                    sync(lock: tableSections! as NSObject){
                        self.tableSections?.remove(at: self.tableSections!.index(of: section)!)
                }
        }
```

Any advice or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible cause is you are removing the elements from array while iterating it.

Try the following and see if you have any issue

```
tableSections = tableSections.filter { $0.itemType != itemType }
```